# How to continue execution after "NoSuchElementException" in Selenium (Java)?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, page-factory

I'm attempting to create an ArrayList of WebElements from this page:

[image]

If all the elements are displayed, they're able to be added to the ArrayList just fine.

```
ArrayList<WebElement> TodoArray = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

                        TodoArray.add(todo1);
```

If I remove one of the elements from the web page(not code) I get this error when running my Test Case:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: *[name='todo[9]']
```

Is there any way to bypass this error and force java to skip the missing element, but continue adding the elements that are displayed?

My code is pretty straight forward. I'm using JUnit to run my test cases. The elements are defined correctly using the @FindBy annotations.

```
@FindBy(name="todo[1]")
    WebElement todo1;
```

I tried surrounding the variables with Try/Catch and using NoSuchElementException, but I wasn't sure how to format it. Is using the "continue" keyword possible in this situation?

Hopefully I provided enough information. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use a try-catch: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp

Comment: Can you be more specific? Whenever I use Try/Catch, my code stops, I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. 

I want to be able to continue execution despite the missing element. If the element is missing, then it shouldn't be added to the ArrayList.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why you are hard coding the list items, I would get the dynamic list of `to do` elements from the application. Something like this `List<WebElement> todoItems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("generic css goes here"));

Comment: @Few_Line post all of your code

Answer (score 2):

The exact syntax for Java Try/Catch would be this for you:

```
try {
  @FindBy(name="todo[1]")
       WebElement todo1;
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
  System.out.println("could not find element todo1");
}
...
//rest of your code
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use fluent wait, this way:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(10, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(1, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

I think this is a more elegant way to do it.